# android convert string to date Exception

Tags: android

When I try to convert string to date an Exception:

```
String da="16-Jan-2014 10:25:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy HH:mm:SS", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date dd = sdf.parse(da);
```

What wrong in my code please?

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:"16-Jan-2014 10:25:00" (at offset 3)
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using small letter 'm's for months. They should be changed to capital letter M's. As described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

So the pattern will be something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:SS", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider Following Example

```
String text = "2014-01-17T00:00:00.000-0500";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Hope this could Help

Comment: This wouldn't work. You still need three M's. Two MM's will parse date the in this format: 16-01-2014. But the given format has a three character month.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by *@Tim Kranen*, the months formats are in capital letters. So it should be `MMM`.

To understand the months formatting consider this short code-

```
/*
  Formatting month using SimpleDateFormat
  This example shows how to format month using Java SimpleDateFormat class. Month can
  be formatted in M, MM, MMM and MMMM formats.  
*/


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class FormattingMonth {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create Date object
    Date date = new Date();

     //formatting month in M format like 1,2 etc
     String strDateFormat = "M";
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);

     System.out.println("Current Month in M format : " + sdf.format(date));

     //formatting Month in MM format like 01, 02 etc.
     strDateFormat = "MM";
     sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
     System.out.println("Current Month in MM format : " + sdf.format(date));

     //formatting Month in MMM format like Jan, Feb etc.
     strDateFormat = "MMM";
     sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
     System.out.println("Current Month in MMM format : " + sdf.format(date));

     //formatting Month in MMMM format like January, February etc.
     strDateFormat = "MMMM";
     sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
     System.out.println("Current Month in MMMM format : " + sdf.format(date));

  }
}

/*
Typical output would be
Current Month in M format : 2
Current Month in MM format : 02
Current Month in MMM format : Feb
Current Month in MMMM format : February
*
```

Check the [Java Date Formatting](http://www.java-examples.com/java-date-formatting) with examples as mentioned above for understanding Formats.